# Using Mootools getElements('[selected] to find if ANY option is selcted

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools1.2

Can someone please help me find if there is any option selected 
I currently have this

```
 var Selected = $$('myslected_id').getElements('[selected]') ;
 if(Selected==null){
       $('selectedresult').set('text','Nothing Selected');
 }else{
       $('selectedresult').set('text','Something Selected');
 }


<div id="selectedresult"></div>


<select id="myslected_id" name="myslected_name"  multiple="multiple">

 <optgroup label="mylabel">
  <option value="1">Value1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Value1</option>
                <option value="3">Value2</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

current form select should output Something Selected

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you misspelled 'myselected_id' on your `<select>`

```
<select id="myselected_id" name="myselected_name"  multiple="multiple">

 <optgroup label="mylabel">
  <option value="1">Value1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Value1</option>
  <option value="3">Value2</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

mootools section

```
var Selected = $$('#myselected_id option[selected]');

if (Selected.length == 0) {
    $('selectedresult').set('html', 'nothing selected');
} else {
    $('selectedresult').set('html', 'Something Selected');
}
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FjnzV/1/)
This will grab all options elements that are selected. Your understanding of usage for $$ isn't correct.  Please read this section.  Also, an empty array does not equal to null in javascript.

[Mootools 1.2.5 Element Doc](http://mootools.net/docs/core125/core/Element/Element)

Comment: you welcome. ya i came from php as well took awhile to understand js.  pelase rep and accept thanks

Comment: i agree with the fact that this works, i'm just not sure why you'd choose to do it that way.  getSelected reads much better semantically, and you could reduce your whole mootools section to $('selectedresult').set('html', $('myselectid').getSelected().length == 0 ? 'nothing selected' : 'something selected').  at least i think you could.  i haven't used mootools in forever.

Comment: hey man, i agree with getSelected reads much better semantically. i just modified the way he see it that's all.

Answer (score 2):

i think you'd be better off using the [getSelected](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3agetSelected) method.  it gets...  the selected stuff. :)

Comment: quite, +1. it's what its there for. works with multiple selects etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you kyjy112 !
I fund another way also but yours is shorter 
yes , im still mixing php array with js , beginer , this is what i came up with var

```
MySelection = $('myselectid');
    MySelection.addEvent('domready', function(){//domready to use on load
    if(MySelection.getElement("[selected]")) {
        //$("oresultdiv").set("text",  MySelection.getElement(":selected").text)
        $("resultdiv").set("text", "Something")
}else {
        $("resultdiv").set("text", "nothing")
}
});
```

Comment: Mootools is definately friendly to developers coming from php.  well, at least from my experience.  its just awesome.  goodluck and thanks for the accept and rep.